# Does Threading.Thread.Sleep accepts ticks?

Tags: .net, thread-sleep

When using Threading.Thread.Sleep in .NET, there is an option to use Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeout As TimeSpan).
Now, in System.TimeSpan there is the option to express period in 100-nanosecond units: System.TimeSpan(ticks as long).
Can Threading.Thread.Sleep work with nanoseconds or it converts them to milliseconds (integer)?
If it converts them to milliseconds I quess there is no way to suspend a thread for less than 1 millisecond. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That falls in the "it depends" category.  You could, say, be using it in a Silverlight app that runs on a Mac.  But a standard Windows desktop app uses the operating system's [Sleep()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call which accepts a sleep time expressed only in milliseconds.

That's not where it ends, by default Windows can only sleep a thread with an accuracy that depends on the operating system clock interrupt.  Which is, by default, 1/64 of a second, 0.015625 seconds on most machines.  So if you Thread.Sleep(1) then you'll actually sleep for about 16 milliseconds.  Or more.

You can jack up the interrupt rate by pinvoking [timeBeginPeriod(1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Sleeps are now accurate to a millisecond, plus or minus a bunch due to scheduling inaccuracies.  Something you should *never* do on a battery-powered machine.  And don't forget to pinvoke timeEndPeriod().

Comment: Thank you Hans, timeBeginPeriod(1) gives better accurancy in Sleep() method, indeed. But why I should not use it on a battery-powered machine?

Comment: Because waking up the processor 16 times more frequently eats up a lot of power.

Comment: Hans, cannot we suppose that <1ms sleep requests are executed in user space by a busy loop calling nop ? I have timed linux usleep function to be incredibly accurate under 1ms in the past (FULL_DYN didn't exist). So I guessed it must have been a spin wait.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is correct and documented in MSDN:

> This overload of Sleep uses the total number of whole milliseconds in timeout. Fractional milliseconds are discarded.

And my understanding is that even the milliseconds value isn't necessarily going to yield a very accurate sleep time down to the millisecond because of the nature of multitasking. When I needed to sleep a very specific amount of time, I used code like this:

```
  long freq;
  long frame;
  freq = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.Frequency;
  frame = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
  while ((frame - fpsStartTime) * fps < freq * fpsFrameCount)
  {
     int sleepTime = (int)((fpsStartTime * fps + freq * fpsFrameCount - frame * fps) * 1000 / (freq * fps));
     if (sleepTime > 0) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
     frame = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
  }
  if (++fpsFrameCount > fps)
  {
     fpsFrameCount = 0;
     fpsStartTime = frame;
  }
```

Comment: So, I guess that this code also doesn't support sleeping less than a millisecond, right?

Comment: It uses sleep to sleep a whole number of milliseconds and then cycles the CPU until the fraction of a millisecond has passed.